# RUN API inside SQL database upload

Tags: php, sql, api

I have an API to do an action for a site.

```
/api/api.php?api=server&ver=1.0&key=**&cmd=ADD_OBJECT,862011228001930
```

The API works and does what it needs to be done. The API information is populated from a form I have. the form also needs to upload information to MYSQL database using SQL

I have the following SQL

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tracking_units SET
                status = 'Tech',
                unit_nr = '".$unit_nr."',
                imei = '".$imei."',
                sysdate = '".$date."',              
                systime = '".$time."',
                controller = '".$slname."',
                branch = 'JHB',
                client = 'eTrack'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); //Retrieve the last ID of the record
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
header("Location: http://***/api/api.php?api=server&ver=1.0&key=***&cmd=ADD_OBJECT,$imei");
```

The above works as the header runs the API, but once the API is completed I would like to redirect the page to another html page. Is this possible with me running the header command.

I am very new to API's and not sure how else I can run the API after the SQL command and then use the header to divert to another page

Comment: 1. You are open to SQL Injection with that SQL, use prepared statement. 2. Yes, you can redirect request to another URL `header('Location: ' . $newUrl);`. 3 Headers can not be used if you have any output - `echo` in else statement

Comment: Why would you redirect to the API, though? Seems like you should use cURL to perform that request and then redirect after that.

Comment: I am using the header currently to execute the API but once it is executed it stays on a blank page, after the API is completed I need to redirect the page to another page. Is there a way to execute the API right after the SQL query,and then use the header to divert page?

Comment: @El_Vanja this is the only way I think I can run the API, As I have never worked with API's before this is new to me. The main end result I need is update the DB and run the API then divert to another page

Comment: Look into [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php).

Comment: @El_Vanja I appreciate your direction on cURL I have edited my question and found this to work. Thank you very much I still use the header as a divert after the sql statement and curl

Comment: If you've reached the solution yourself, please remove the working code from your question and post it as an answer (you're allowed to answer your own questions) and accept it. That way filters will work correctly, if you edit the solution into the question then it's still considered unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this to work

```
$ch = curl_init("http://***/api/api.php?api=server&ver=1.0&key=***&cmd=ADD_OBJECT,$imei,$unit_nr,false,2021-01-01");

curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    fwrite($ch, curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
fclose($ch);
```